# Formatting as a currency on a VF page

Tags: visualforce, formatting, currency

I'm trying to render a currency value to a VF page.  Whether I use Decimal or String, it still doesn't seem to work with the OutputText formatting :-

```
 <apex:column>
      <apex:facet name="header">AUM</apex:facet>
      <apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}" />
      <apex:param value="{!product.AUMString}" />
  </apex:column>
```

Instead, it only renders the literal string **{0, Number, Currency}**

What's needed here to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One small change required, declare the `apex:param` tag inside the `apex:outputText`.

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">AUM</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}" >
        <apex:param value="{!product.AUMString}" />
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:column>
```